# The method list.pop returns None instead of the value intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just trying out this method .pop() and it says in the docs it is supposed to "Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it."

So I tried the following code:

```
def lao(li, i):
    guess=input('Have a guess: ')
    if guess == li[i]:
        li.pop(i)

ho=list('abcde')
```

I wanted to see if lao(ho, 0) returned and removed 'a' as I thought it would, and this is how it went:

```
>>> print(lao(ho, 0))
Have a guess: a
None

>>> ho
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

So clearly the .pop() method was executed since 'a' was removed but the method didn't return 'a', instead it returned None.
I don't understand why?

Answer (score 3):

Change `li.pop(i)` to `return li.pop(i)`. Python functions return `None` by default (when no `return` statement is present/reached). To return something from the function you must use the `return` keyword. See a [demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/inhE5c).

Comment: Ok, haha how stupid of me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `return li.pop(i)`?

The method is probably working correctly, it's just that you are not returnning an actual value